# Toggle value of button text on click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to toggle the value of a button text on click with the following directive:

```
   .directive('startstop', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input value="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.bind("click", function(){
            console.log('startstop clicked', elem)
            if(elem.val() == "start") {
               elem.val("stop");   
            }
            else {
               elem.val("start");
            }
          })
        }
      }
   });
```

i am able to detect click events and it appears the value is actually being modified when i view elem directly in the console...but i dont see the value of the button update.
How can i get this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `restrict: 'E'` to `restrict: 'A'` and you code works great.
This is the template

```
<input type="button" startstop value="button"></input>
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GAt7M/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalvasani/wqsyf/2/)

Can you check below code:

Template code:

```
<startstop></startstop>
```

Directive Code:

```
directive('startstop', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<input type="button" value="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.bind("click", function(){
            console.log('startstop clicked', elem)
            if(elem.val() == "start") {
               elem.val("stop");   
            }
            else {
               elem.val("start");
            }

          })
        }
      }
   });
```